# Why does the C standard provide unsized types (int, long long, char vs. int32_t, int64_t, uint8_t etc.)?

Tags: objective-c, c

Why weren't the contents of stdint.h *the* standard when it was included in the standard (no int no short no float, but int32_t, int16_t, float32_t etc.)?  What advantage did/does ambiguous type sizes provide?

In objective-C, why was it decided that `CGFloat`, `NSInteger`, `NSUInteger` have different sizes on different platforms?

Comment: Title and body seem in disagreement: Are you wondering why they didn't make the primitive types fixed-size to begin with, or why these types are still available and in common use in the face of the fixed-sized alternatives?

Comment: “What advantage did/does ambiguous type sizes provide?” I used to (and still do) wonder about this, too. Maybe it’s just the fact that sometimes being “native” to the processor (and the speed benefit this brings) is more important than being unambiguous.

Comment: @delnan I guess I meant to ask why as an ongoing basis C is still written as int i = 0; float f = 1.0f; long l = 3l rather than taking the time to explicitly specify the storage size.

Comment: One obvious advantage is precisely that you *don't* have to explicitly specify the storage size. Turning it around, if all you need is a rather vaguely specified "small integer" then what is the advantage of being compelled to specify the size rather than just using a plain `int`? I don't see why only using fixed size integer types (which are optional in the standard anyway) should be automatically assumed to be better, unless an advantage for the regular types can be demonstrated.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths When I need a vaguely specified "small integer", I pick a fixed size as a guesstimate with generous error margin (default to u64). Using an `int` here buys me nothing, and it prevents me from reasoning about overflow and other limits in a platform-agnostic manner. When I use an `u32` I know it goes from 0 to 4 billion. I can work with that. I can say "that supports 4 GiB files and that's okay". When I use an `int` I know next to next to nothing, and furthermore risk that inputs that work well on one platform lead to overflow on others, for absolutely no good reason.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths the problem which prompted this question lies in the implementation of NSNotFound which was defined previously as 0x7F FF FF FF (the largest signed value).  A library I use worked fine until NSInteger compiled to 8 bytes which secretly caused my program to blow up :(.  My immediate thought was why would you use an NSInteger to compare against a 32-bit value, and in this case if the size was provided to begin with it would've kept working all along.

Comment: @delnan: Sure, if you *need* a minimum size other than the defaults, obviously these additional types are useful, that's why they are there. 4 billion is not a "small integer", it's a pretty large one. But a lot of the times, you don't need that. Without doing any actual checking, I'd suspect that the vast majority of the times I want an integer, 32,000 is just "far more than enough", so in those cases that's all that matters. It's possible to make a case that specifying a fixed size type is actually *less* semantically meaningful when you genuinely don't care about the size.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths We *never* "genuinely don't care about the size". We need to store *something*, and when that something overflows we're sad. 4 billion is indeed not a "small integer" -- that is why I chose u32 to store the "small integer", because I am confident that it's large enough to hold any "small integer" (signedness not accounted for). That's also why I like arbitrary precision integers, then I don't have to worry about overflow at all and don't have to make any choice. But since those are inconvenient and big and slow, I settle for "probably large enough".

Comment: @delnan: Sure there are times when we genuinely don't care about the size, because we have guaranteed minimums. `int` is guaranteed to be at least 16 bits, so if you check your input and it's less than that, you don't care about the size, because you know it's big enough. If you don't check your input, you can overflow any type, fixed precision integers don't give you an automatic escape from that. If you're just worried about avoiding overflow, there is no benefit to choosing an `int32_t` (which is not guaranteed to be available) over a `long` (which is), for instance.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Ah, so you're talking about not caring about the *exact* size but only about the minimum. Of course you can choose those to be large enough, and of course any particular word size can be overflown. But since I can't rely on anything beyond the minimum size, any additional bit is wasted (I can't even use it as error margin, I have to out the error margin into the minimum size). The only thing I "gained" is that *sometimes* things which *would* normally overflow *don't*, in other words, sometimes bugs (in my guesstimate or my overflow-checking code) are masked.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths As for availability: It is only a minor obstacle, if at all. All major toolchains have `[u]intX_t` now (and other languages always have those types), even VS since a few years ago. If I target something that doesn't have them, it probably only takes a quick search and a conditional typedef to make it my own. If there isn't any type of the desires size at all, there also isn't any non-fixed-size type with the desired *minimum* size either, so we'd both be screwed.

Comment: @delnan: Yes, and you can always use `int_least32_t` anyway. I get the point about masking potential bugs that might occur on other systems, and sometimes that might be a real concern. But, to take a trite (yet common) example, with `for ( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) { ...` I'll accept the chance that there's a theoretical possibility I'm being human and missing some potential overflow bug in there, in return for not having to worry about sizes and cluttering things up. If nothing else, it'll free up more of my attention for maybe spotting more likely ones.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, in such a case I wouldn't worry too much either. On the other hand, I welcome any systems language that makes fixed-sized types the default and at least as convenient as any type with uncertain exact size. Such as Rust, where `i32` is as short as `int` and the unsigned types are much shorter than the C versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When C was designed, there were computers with different word sizes.  Not just multiples of 8, but other sizes like the 18-bit word size on the PDP-7.  So sometimes an `int` was 16 bits, but maybe it was 18 bits, or 32 bits, or some other size entirely.  On a Cray-1 an `int` was 64 bits.  As a result, `int` meant "whatever is convenient for this computer, but at least 16 bits".

That was about forty years ago.  Computers have changed, so it certainly looks odd *now*.

`NSInteger` is used to denote the computer's word size, since it makes no sense to ask for the 5 billionth element of an array on a 32-bit system, but it makes perfect sense on a 64-bit system.

I can't speak for why `CGFloat` is a `double` on 64-bit system.  That baffles me.

Comment: perhaps there's an efficiency cross-over when using 64-bit doubles vs 32-bit float on a 64-bit architecture

Comment: @nielsbot: There isn't.  Even on 32-bit systems, the floating point registers weren't narrower than 64 bits (speaking of x86 and PowerPC).

Comment: @DietrichEpp then wouldn't an acceptable (and purely speculative) answer be simply "caches and storage got bigger; it seemed like an opportune moment to grab some extra precision"?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I think your last statement should be "I can't speak for why CGFloat is a float on 32-bit systems" since per your comment there are no single precision registers in x86 or PPC ?

Comment: @Tommy With floating point even more than with integers, extra precision is a nuisance rather than a boon when it comes unexpectedly and platform-dependently. It makes debugging numeric stability issues harder, and those issues exist regardless of how much precision you have. Of course, the people who made that decision might disagree, this is just why I am also surprised (and opposed to) this move.

Comment: @delnan those arguments just sound like classic Apple to me. In two years there'll be no ongoing support for any 32-bit runtime. At that stage do they want to still be using 32-bit floats just because a transition a while ago would have been a little extra effort for a few people? Compared to completely changing processor architectures twice in 30 years, it's small potatoes.

Comment: @Tommy That is an excellent point, when you *switch* platforms rather than *add* more (with a relatively short transition period) it makes some amount of sense to break compatibility.

Comment: @RyanDignard: There are no separate single-precision registers (that would be silly!) but there are single-precision operations.

Comment: @Tommy: I think you misunderstand the relationship of the size of your floating-point numbers to the processor word width.  Whether you use 32-bit or 64-bit floats is a completely *separate* question from the question of whether you are using a 32-bit or 64-bit architecture.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I don't think I do since I haven't said anything that would suggest I believe that. As I said: "caches and storage got bigger; it seemed like an opportune moment to grab some extra precision". i.e. the memory footprint is greater with 64 bit. The cache footprint is bigger. So it was simply an opportune moment to push developers forwards, rather than sticking with a legacy decision for the entire rest of history. Apple had to offer separate compilations of all the libraries anyway.

Comment: @Tommy: Ah, I didn't understand what you were saying.

Answer (score 2):

C is meant to be portable from enbedded devices, over your phone, to descktops, mainfraimes and beyond. These don't have the same base types, e.g the later may have `uint128_t` where others don't. Writing code with fixed width types would severely restrict portability in some cases.

This is why with preference you should neither use `uintX_t` nor `int`, `long` etc but the semantic typedefs such as `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t`. These are really the ones that make your code portable.

Comment: Why would it restrict portability? Some quantities are inherently platform-dependent, such as the largest possible index into an array. For those, implementation-provided semantic typedefs are fine. But when you have something whose range depends solely on *your* problem domain and how you choose to model it, selecting some fixed size should not affect portability at all (simulating a `uint128_t` on a cheap ARM is actually rather easy, and it beats *not working*). The question is about `unsigned`, `short`, `long` and such, which have neither semantically meaningful ranges nor fixed size.